# Unhandled exception in "msvcp90d.dll"?

Tags: c++, unhandled-exception

I'm a fairly new programmer so please bear with me on this. I am using VC++ 2008.

I am getting this error from my program:

> Unhandled exception at 0x68bce2ba (msvcp90d.dll) in z projection.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00630067.

The computer then brings me to this page of code which looks rather confusing and something I definitely did not write. It points to this section of code as being the offending code (maerked by "<-computer points to this line"):

```
public:
_CRTIMP2_PURE static size_t __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL _Getcat(const facet ** = 0,
    const locale * = 0)
{   // get category value, or -1 if no corresponding C category
    return ((size_t)(-1));
}

_CRTIMP2_PURE void __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Incref()
{   // safely increment the reference count
    _BEGIN_LOCK(_LOCK_LOCALE)
        if (_Refs < (size_t)(-1))
            ++_Refs;      <-computer points to this line
    _END_LOCK()
}

_CRTIMP2_PURE facet *__CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Decref()
{   // safely decrement the reference count, return this when dead
    _BEGIN_LOCK(_LOCK_LOCALE)
    if (0 < _Refs && _Refs < (size_t)(-1))
        --_Refs;
    return (_Refs == 0 ? this : 0);
    _END_LOCK()
}
```

I have narrowed it down to the line of code in my own program that is likely causing the crash (4th line of code starting with "index", also stage = 1):

```
stringstream index;
string fileName = "";
index.str("");//

index << setw( 3 ) << setfill( '0' ) << stage - 1;

fileName = "positive Z topography-" + index.str() + ".txt";
```

The thing that baffles me is that I copied and pasted this code out of another program i wrote that has run hundreds of times without any trouble what so ever.

Edit: here is the entire code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int dim = 100;
    int steps = 9;  //step 0 = 1, steps = actual steps + 1
    int spread = 5; //number of points averaged to get a slope, must be an odd number
    int halfSpread = (spread - 1)/2; //redefine for eazier use in program (better efficency)

    char * partMap = new char [dim * dim * dim]; // cad data

    // positive and negitive denote the x direction the check is moving in. Positive is  0 -> x, negitive is x -> 0.
    unsigned short int * positiveProjection = new unsigned short int [dim * dim]; //projection arrays
    unsigned short int * negitiveProjection = new unsigned short int [dim * dim];

    unsigned short int * negitiveThickness = new unsigned short int [dim * dim];

    double * negitiveXGradient = new double [dim * dim];
    double * negitiveYGradient = new double [dim * dim];

    stringstream index;
    string fileName;

    ifstream txtFile;
    txtFile.open("3D CAD Part.txt");
    txtFile.read(partMap, dim * dim * dim);
    txtFile.close();


    for (int stage = 1; stage < steps; stage++)
    {

        cout << "stage " << stage << endl;

        //z axis projections
        //projection order is along x then along y, during each step, along z in both directions

        int k = 0; // z axis loop variable

        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            {
                k = 0;

                while ((k != dim) && partMap[dim * ((dim - 1 - k) + dim * i) + j] < stage) 
                    k++;
                positiveProjection[dim * k + j] = k;

                k = dim;

                while ((k != 0) && partMap[dim * ((dim - 1 - (k - 1)) + dim * i) + j] < stage) 
                    k--;
                negitiveProjection[dim * k + j] = i;

                while ((k != 0) && partMap[dim * ((dim - 1 - (k - 1)) + dim * i) + j] >= stage) 
                    k--;
                negitiveThickness[dim * k + j] = negitiveProjection[dim * k + j] - k;
            }
        }

        // negitive dz/dx gradient
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
        {

            //first loop to handle the first edge gradients
            for (int i = 0; i < halfSpread; i++)
                negitiveXGradient[(j * dim) + i] = (double(negitiveProjection[(j * dim) + halfSpread + i]) - double(negitiveProjection[j * dim]))/(halfSpread + i); // untested

            //second loop to handle the main middle section
            for (int i = halfSpread; i < dim - halfSpread; i++)
                negitiveXGradient[(j * dim) + i] = (double(negitiveProjection[(j * dim) + i + halfSpread]) - double(negitiveProjection[(j * dim) + i - halfSpread]))/ (spread - 1); // untested

            //third loop to handle the end edge gradients
            for (int i = dim - halfSpread; i < dim; i++)
                negitiveXGradient[(j * dim) + i] = (double(negitiveProjection[(j * dim) + dim - 1]) - double(negitiveProjection[j * dim + i - halfSpread]))/((dim - 1) - i + halfSpread); // untested
        }

        // negitive dz/dy gradient
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        {
            //first loop to handle the first edge gradients
            for (int j = 0; j < halfSpread; j++)
                negitiveYGradient[(j * dim) + i] = (double(negitiveProjection[((j + halfSpread) * dim) + i]) - double(negitiveProjection[i]))/(halfSpread + j); // untested

            //second loop to handle the main middle section
            for (int j = halfSpread; j < dim - halfSpread; j++)
                negitiveYGradient[(j * dim) + i] = (double(negitiveProjection[((j + halfSpread) * dim) + i]) - double(negitiveProjection[((j - halfSpread) * dim) + i]))/ (spread - 1); // untested

            //third loop to handle the end edge gradients
            for (int j = dim - halfSpread; j < dim; j++)
                negitiveYGradient[(j * dim) + i] = (double(negitiveProjection[(dim * (dim - 1)) + i]) - double(negitiveProjection[((j - halfSpread) * dim) + i]))/((dim - 1) - j + halfSpread); // untested
        }

        fileName = ""; // reset string and stringstream
        index.str("");//

        index << setw( 3 ) << setfill( '0' ) << stage - 1; // set index, index is -1 of stage due to the program structure

        fileName = "positive Z topography-" + index.str() + ".txt";

        ofstream outputFile1(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
        outputFile1.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(positiveProjection), streamsize(dim * dim * sizeof(unsigned short int)));
        outputFile1.close();

        fileName = "negitive Z topography-" + index.str() + ".txt";

        ofstream outputFile2(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
        outputFile2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(negitiveProjection), streamsize(dim * dim * sizeof(unsigned short int)));
        outputFile2.close();

        fileName = "negitive Z thickness-" + index.str() + ".txt";

        ofstream outputFile4(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
        outputFile4.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(negitiveThickness), streamsize(dim * dim * sizeof(unsigned short int)));    
        outputFile4.close();

        fileName = "negitive Z X gradient-" + index.str() + ".txt";

        ofstream outputFile5(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
        outputFile5.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(negitiveXGradient), streamsize(dim * dim * sizeof(double)));
        outputFile5.close();

        fileName = "negitive Z Y gradient-" + index.str() + ".txt";

        ofstream outputFile6(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
        outputFile6.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(negitiveYGradient), streamsize(dim * dim * sizeof(double)));
        outputFile6.close();
    }
}
```

Ok, everything is fine until the last chunk of code where I start to output my results to hard drive. I used the breakpoints in VC++ and the last breakpoint to pass through successfully before an error is at the point mentioned earlier (the second block of code I posted). And apparently HTML doesn't like my c++ code either.

Oh, also, save yourself the trouble of going through the loops...they should be fine...there's like a dozen loops in there, you don't need to worry about whats going on in them, they are pretty safe. I only have problems with the last chunk.

Comment: Is this the code copied as-is from your program?

Comment: this is almost as copied from my program, except i declared stringstream index and string filename earlier.

There are no variables to worry about, all you need to know about variables is that stage = 1 (i stated that).

the large chunk of code above IS NOT MINE. i haven't the first clue why its there or whats wrong with it only that my debugger says its bad...

Comment: Is this code part of a class, and index and filename are members? That's the only reason I could think of for index's member data to be invalid. Unless you have code earlier in the function that blows the stack... Could you post the whole routine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the problems appears to arise with the last chunk doesn't necessarily mean that there are no errors in your loops. If you go out of bounds on any of your arrays you may not get any indication about it until later on.

In the first interior `while` loop you have

```
while ((k != dim) && partMap[dim * ((dim - 1 - k) + dim * i) + j] < stage) 
    k++;
```

which means that potentially `k` could have the value `dim` when finished with the `while` loop. The next line then does

```
positiveProjection[dim * k + j] = k;
```

which will go out of bounds in `positiveProjection` for any `j` since you're trying to index with `dim*dim + j` and it only has dimension `dim*dim`.

Comment: Nice! I suspected as much, but didn't have the energy to walk through the loops.

Comment: Hmm...it seems you solved my problem, even though it wasnt want i had expected. Thank you very much!

yes, your right. Actually, i had neglected to change the variables around when i coped and pasted this code out of another program (you can guess at the other program names, x projection, y projection). The program runs now...i just need to verify the outputs.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm a fairly new programmer so please
>   bear with me on this.

Ok. I promise not to make fun of you ;)

> The computer then brings me to this
>   page of code

You probably mean that the Visual Studio debugger brings you to this line. You can use the 'stack trace' feature to find the exact location where things go wrong: click menu Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack.

However, I can't find anything wrong in your code. This simple application works perfectly:

```
int main()
{

    std::stringstream index;
    std::string fileName = "";
    index.str("");//
    int stage = 1;
    index << std::setw( 3 ) << std::setfill( '0' ) << stage - 1; 
    fileName = "positive Z topography-" + index.str() + ".txt";
    std::cout << "Done with test.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So in order to help you, we need to see more of your code...

Comment: +1 Beginners don't realize the benefits of seeing the Call Stack